# Excel 2016: sort highest weight and duplicate values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a worksheet with weight values and serial duplicate #s. I'd like to sort the weight so that the highest weight value is followed by the weight values with the same serial dup # in descending order. The next highest weight value would follow with the values from the corresponding serial dup #.

[screen shot of partial data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WL8bq.jpg)

In the example above: The Weight Rank in A3 is the first value with a duplicate value in column B (B3 and B17). I would like to be able to sort the sheet so that row B17 is directly below B3.

I've tried using the sort function, adding multiple lines. I've tried loading the data in google sheets and using their sort formula. I haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a MINIFS formula in a new column. I rearranged your data a little, but doesn't matter here:

```
=MINIFS($C$2:$C$6,$A$2:$A$6,A2)
```

So it's look at the current row's serial#, then finding the smallest Weight Rank in columnn C for all matching serial numbers.

[image]

Then sort by Adjusted_Rank (smallest first) then weight (largest first).

Comment: So far this looks great, though my version of Excel 2016 does not include MINIFS. I found this work around by entering it as an array (Ctrl+Shift+Enter): =MIN(IF($A$2:$A$17=A2,$C$2:$C$17)).  Thanks for the help